# CKeditor replace h-card span

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4

I am using ckeditor 4 as follows `CKEDITOR.replace('texto-anexo', {

```
        });`
```

but in a part of the text that comes from the bank

```
<p style="text-align:justify"><span class="h-card" id="DescricaoDasAtividades"><p>Etapa 01: Reuni&atilde;o para elaborar o briefing;<br />
Etapa 02: Desenvolvimento de propostas preliminares para a embalagem;<br />
Etapa 03: Apresenta&ccedil;&atilde;o e valida&ccedil;&atilde;o das propostas de desenhos preliminares da embalagem;<br />
Etapa 04: Elabora&ccedil;&atilde;o do relat&oacute;rio final e apresenta&ccedil;&atilde;o do mesmo para o cliente, contendo a s&iacute;ntese das etapas e a arte final da embalagem. &nbsp;</p>
</span></p>
```

he is deleting the span leaving the code like this

```
<p>Etapa 01: Reuni&atilde;o para elaborar o briefing;<br />
Etapa 02: Desenvolvimento de propostas preliminares para a embalagem;<br />
Etapa 03: Apresenta&ccedil;&atilde;o e valida&ccedil;&atilde;o das propostas de desenhos preliminares da embalagem;<br />
Etapa 04: Elabora&ccedil;&atilde;o do relat&oacute;rio final e apresenta&ccedil;&atilde;o do mesmo para o cliente, contendo a s&iacute;ntese das etapas e a arte final da embalagem.</p>
```

How do I make him not make this modification?

I tried to make this following modification in replace but it didn't work

```
CKEDITOR.replace('texto-anexo', {
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
    allowedContent: true,
    cleaning: false,
    autoParagraph: false
});
```

Comment: The problem that you are experiencing is probably the fact that the original code is not valid syntax. Paragraph tags can't have paragraph tags as children.